# Unix - Rename a file by removing last 2 instances of a character

Tags: unix, rename

I need to rename some files on Unix. I want to truncate the last two underscores and anything that follows them. For example:

> abc_def_ghi_121222_as.csv              --> abc_def_ghi.csv
>
> xy_cv_sac_bnmkj_ppa_jkl_lkkjll.csv     --> xy_cv_sac_bnmkj_ppa.csv

How can I achieve this?

Comment: For completeness' sake: which Unix? FreeBSD, OpenBSD, AIX, HPUX, Solaris, ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

for FILE in $(ls)
do
  if [[ $FILE =~ csv$ ]]; then
    [[ $FILE =~ ^(.*)_(.*)_(.*).csv$ ]]
    NEWFILENAME="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}.csv"
    mv $FILE $NEWFILENAME
  fi
done
```

Put it in the folder in which you want to rename the files and run it. It will rename all files ending in `csv` from their current name to the name before the last 2 underscores.

Comment: @mestia Feel free to add your own answer or add it to my post :) If I need to hack up something quickly I usually use one-liners as well, but if I need it more than once, or need to explain it to someone else, I use a full-fledged script.

Comment: sorry, it seems that I am not able to post the code, the markup gets screwed up. another nice way to strip 2 last elements: ` ls -1 *.csv |rev |cut -d\_ -f2- | rev`

Comment: Thanks @mtak @mestia i also found another way but its only a workaround for f in *[0-9]*.csv; do x=`echo $f|cut -d. -f1`; y=`echo $x|rev|sed -e 's/_/$/1'|rev` ; z=`echo $y|cut -d$ -f1`".csv" ; echo mv "${f}" "${z}"; done

Comment: Why do you use `for FILE in $(ls)`? This will fail if there is a file name with a space in it; for example, a file called `foo bar` will cause your command to look for a file called `foo` and then a file called `bar`. `for FILE in *` is simpler and safer. And you can remove the test on the filename by using `*_*_*.csv` or `*_*_*`. Also, it’s common to use lower case for the names of local variables in shell scripts; e.g., `for file in *`. (Yes, I know that environment variables are conventionally capitalized.)

Comment: @Scott Why I use `for FILE in $(ls)`? Because it's an answer to the question. If the asker would've said that there were spaces in his filenames I would have given him a solution for that. As for the capitalization, where I come from it's not common for Bash variables to be lower case ('conventions' for Bash scripting are not very well established). You're more than welcome to post an answer of your own or edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @mtak @mestia i have an alternate as well

```
 for f in *[0-9]*.csv;  
do  
x=`echo  $f|cut -d. -f1`; 
y=`echo $x|rev|sed -e 's/_/$/1'|rev` ; 
z=`echo $y|cut -d$ -f1`".csv"  ; 
echo mv "${f}" "${z}";  
done
```

Thanks,
S.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Perl `rename` to accomplish this. It should come with the Perl distribution; in Debian, it's packaged as a part of the [perl package](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/perl) under the name `prename` with an alias to `rename`.

**For example:**

```
$ ls -1
$ touch abc_def_ghi_121222_as.csv xy_cv_sac_bnmkj_ppa_jkl_lkkjll.csv
$ ls -1
abc_def_ghi_121222_as.csv
xy_cv_sac_bnmkj_ppa_jkl_lkkjll.csv
$ rename 's/_[^_]*_[^_]*\.csv$/.csv/' *
$ ls -1
abc_def_ghi.csv
xy_cv_sac_bnmkj_ppa.csv
$
```

This processes all file names given, applying the provided [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions) and renames each file to the result.

Perl should be available on most systems, so while not strictly a shell solution this shouldn't count as exotic.